Как сделать так, чтобы tg-бот на базе Aiogram присылал рандомные изображения?
Бот на базе Aiogram в Python. Мне нужно, чтобы бот в ответ на сообщение пользователя присылал не одну фотографию(как я прописала в коде на скрине),а рандомную фотографию из нескольких фото
Как это сделать?


Для этого нужно использовать функцию random.choice, выбирающий случайный элемент из списка.
# тут код импорта aiogram и объявления фото
import random
@dp.message(F.text.contains('макс'))
async def max(message: Message):
    random_value = random.random()
    if random_value >= 0.6: # Отправляем фото только в 40 % случаев. Блок else не нужен
        # Выбираем случайное фото
        random_photo = random.choice([m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7])
        
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=random_photo)

